# How to get string formate from response of HTTP GET in Python?

Tags: python, http, get

I have the following task

Write a function named "get_response" that three string parameters representing the protocol, name of a server, and a path for an HTTP GET request in this order. Return the response of an HTTPS GET request to the url formed by these inputs. The response should be returned as a string

I wrote the following code.

```
def get_response(protocol, server, path):
str = protocol + "://" + server + "/" + path
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(str).read()

return contents
```

I get the following thing when I run the code

> b'pupils'

What the question wants is the string format and only "pupils" in the answer. I try to convert it into str, but it's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use decode

```
import urllib.request


def get_response(protocol, server, path):
    str = protocol + "://" + server + "/" + path
    contents = urllib.request.urlopen(str).read()

    return contents.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Ignore the indentation.